# Radio button's change event doesn't fire in WebKit when using keyboard for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, radio-button

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/55ucw/1/

In any browser other than Safari or Chrome, I can tab into a set of radio buttons and select one using the arrow keys and the change event will fire.

In Safari or Chrome, I can tab into a radio group, and select a radio button with arrow keys, but the change event never fires.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a solution a bit longer, I came across this blog post: http://evilstreak.co.uk/blog/fixing-change-events-on-radios

This gets the job done.